# Laravel: extraer elementos de una colección y ordenarlos de mayor a menor

Tags: laravel, eloquent, colecciones

Tengo un modelo llamado Personas, que guarda la ciudad a la que pertenece cada persona existente en la tabla...

```
class Persona extends Model
{
    public function ciudad() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Ciudad::class);
    }
}
```

Obtengo todas las personas en el controlador con su ciudad...

```
$personas = Persona::with('ciudad')->orderBy('id')->get();
```

Esto es lo que necesito: generar un **array** o una **colección** (no importa que tipo de matriz) con el id, el nombre de la ciudad y la cantidad de personas que exiten con cada una, además **ordenadas por su mayor cantidad de personas**. Algo así:

```
Collection {#374 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => Ciudad {
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "id" => 105
        "nombre" => "Ciudad de México"
        "cantidad" => 87
      ]
    }
    1 => Ciudad {#382 ▼
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "id" => 323
        "nombre" => "Guadalajara"
        "cantidad" => 64

      ]
    }
    2 => Ciudad {#383 ▼
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "id" => 788
        "nombre" => "Monterrrey"
        "cantidad" => 47
      ]
    }
    3 => Ciudad {#384 ▼
      #attributes: array:3 [▼
        "id" => 27
        "nombre" => "Acapulco"
        "cantidad" => 12
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

En este ejemplo, 87 personas pertenecen al DF, 64 a Guadalajara, 47 a Monterrey, 12 a Acapulco, y así va disminuyendo la cantidad. Así la necesito: no ordenada por ID, o por nombre de la ciudad. Ordenada por cantidad de personas en el modelo Persona.

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas lo que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Cuando pongo en la pregunta todo lo que he hecho para resolver el problema, queda demasiado saturada y he visto cómo, mientras más detallado lo haga, menos ayuda recibo.

Comment: Puedes leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para guiarte. También [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [¿Qué debo hacer si nadie contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Gracias por estar tan atento porloscerros! Ya mismo empezaré a subsanar esas preguntas y ponerme al día.

Comment: Algo que puedes probar, es hacer la [consulta](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models) sobre el modelo Ciudad, contando la cantidad de modelos Persona que le pertenecen con [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models),  Tendrías que tener definida la relación `personas()` [Cada Ciudad tiene muchas Persona](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many).

Comment: Y para ordenar por el campo con la cantidad de personas que tendrá el resultado, puedes usar [orderBy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset).